# Zooming Issue in downloaded pdf file using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am downloading big height web page like 15 pages height, but when I am download showing not clean when zoom plus then see data, how pdf generate default zoom with a full screen like the page.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [400, 4000]);

        doc.addHTML(document.body, function () {
            doc.save('application.pdf');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Below is my screen shot of my download pdf

[image]